# TypeScript declare type of useState hook as prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to send props to a children and one of the props is the `useState` itself. If I declare the type as just `Function` I get an error about needing to be more specific and If I use void I get `Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.`

How do you declare the type for a `setState` hook?

app.tsx

```
import React, { useState } form 'react'
import Component from './component'

const App = () => {
 
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState>string>('')
 
  return (
    <Component 
      foo={foo}
      setFoo={setFoo}
    />
  )

}
```

component.tsx

```
import React, { FC } from 'react'

type Props  = {
  thing: string,
  setFoo: () => void // This fails I do not know how to declare the type for this, it takes a string
}

const Component: FC<Props> = ({ foo, setFoo}) => (
   <>
     <input onChange={e => setFoo(e.target.value} />
   </>
)

export default Component
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setFoo` is called with a string, as in `setFoo("foo")`. So the type is `(_: string) => void`. (The `_` is just a placeholder variable name, you could also use a more detailed name like `(foo: string) => void` — it doesn't matter.)

The useState hook also allows [**functional updates**](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates). This is a way of avoiding problems when computing new state based on the previous state. To use this, you pass a *function* to the setter which receives the old value and returns the new value: `setFoo((oldFoo) => oldFoo + "bar")`

If you want your Component to be able to use functional updates as well, you'll need to include that in the type: `(_: string | (oldValue: string) => string) => void`.

Comment: Added some details about functional state updates.

Comment: You can see the TypeScript type definitions [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/baa2dd2f56dcaf24ea336b65a8618e52120f8d7d/types/react/index.d.ts#L919). The definition of SetStateAction is [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/baa2dd2f56dcaf24ea336b65a8618e52120f8d7d/types/react/index.d.ts#L877). If you want, it should be possible to import & use these types so you can just use `Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>`.